# html canvas children count

Tags: html, canvas

Is there a way to get the count of elements on a canvas? I have some code that adds images to a canvas, somewhere along the line sometimes some of the images fail. I want to run some code afterwards only if there's more than one image on the canvas, how can i get a count of the number of images on the canvas? thank you

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is that a canvas doesn't have "memory", it draws what you throw at it, but it won't "know" how many images are there. All the canvas knows is that you've put content on it, whether that's one big image or several smaller ones is up to you to tell.

What this means is that if you are drawing to a canvas, you have to keep track and count of what you draw yourself. That is, whenever you draw an image on a canvas increase a counter, decrease it when you clear the area it occupied, or reset it whenever you clear the entire canvas. If it sounds simple it's because it is, you just have to remember to do it yourself.